# Write each column of each row as a separate file to S3 using PySpark

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, user-defined-functions, amazon-emr

I have a use case where the program needs to write each column in a dataframe as a separate file to S3, or HDFS on EMR. I am doing some processing on raw data and the output data frame looks like this;

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    id|         processed_1|         processed_2|         processed_3|               error|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|324650|some processed data |some processed data | some processed data|                null|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

For the 3 columns `processed_1`, `processed_2`, `processed_3`,
I want to store each column of each row in a separate file. I have 100k rows of processed data. I tried to do it using UDF and Python;

```
def writeToDisk(doc_id,error, processed_1, processed_2, processed_3):
    
    try:
        if error is None:
            with open(r'hdfs://processed_1.json'.format(doc_id),'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write(processed_1)

            with open(r'hdfs://processed_2.json'.format(doc_id),'w') as f:
                f.write(processed_2)
                
            with open(r'hdfs://processed_3.json'.format(doc_id),'w') as f:
                f.write(processed_3)

            return "SUCCESS"
        
        else:
            error_prefix='{} - root - ERROR - '.format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

            final_error_msg='{}{}'.format(error_prefix,error)

            with open(r'hdfs://error.log'.format(doc_id),'w') as f:
                f.write(unprocessed_html)

            
            return "SUCCESS"
    
    except Exception as e:

        with open(r'hdfs://error.log','w') as f:
            f.write("Failed : {}".format(str(e)))

        return "FAILED"
```

And register the above function as a udf and use it in as;

```
store_data_udf = udf(writeToDisk, StringType())

stored_data = final_data.withColumn("store_results",store_data_udf("id","error","processed_1","processed_2","processed_3"))
```

The above approach does not work. I am not sure what am I missing here.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this task would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to HDFS using python write file functions. Instead, you can create 3 separate dataframes with required columns and write it to hdfs/s3.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import  monotonically_increasing_id

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

file_1 = {"id": 1, "error": 20, 'processed_1': "test", 'processed_2': "test2", 'processed_3': "test3"}

file_2 = {"id": 2, "error": 30, 'processed_1': "test5", 'processed_2': "test6", 'processed_3': "test7"}

final_data = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([file_1,file_2]))

df1=final_data.select("id","error","processed_1").withColumn("num", monotonically_increasing_id())
df2=final_data.select("id","error","processed_2").withColumn("num", monotonically_increasing_id())
df3=final_data.select("id","error","processed_3").withColumn("num", monotonically_increasing_id())

df1.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("num").parquet("df1/")
df2.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("num").parquet("df2/")
df3.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("num").parquet("df3/")
```

Comment: but it will store the entire column. I want to store each column of each row in a separate file. Albeit, it's a start...

Comment: You can add a row number to each record and use `partitionBy` that new column, so each record will be stored in each folder. You can try that or I can update the answer.

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: @srikanthholur, why `monotonically_increasing_id()` and not `lit(1)`, `lit(2)` & `lit(3)` to store these as in 3 different directories?

Comment: He needs each record in separate file. Lit will add same value to all the records.